# Typescript object that uses promises/async not populating correctly

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, es6-promise

I have some code that tries to create a list of 'Documentation' objects are comprised of the path to the document, and the raw text contained inside the document. The code iterates over the CONFIG object (which just maps a section name to a list of ConfigItems), collecting the path to the documentation as well as the promise from the request, and then calls Promise.all() on the promises in attempt to populate the documents object in one go when all the data is available.

```
const get = makeGetRequest('', 'application/text');
type Documentation = { path: string; rawText: string };
declare const CONFIG: Map<string, ConfigItem[]>;

/*
// from ConfigItem class
export interface ConfigItem {
    subItem: boolean;
    source: string;
}
// from seperate class
export declare const makeGetRequest: (apiUrl: string, dataType?: string) => (endpointUrl: string) => Promise<Response>;
*/

async function createDocs() {
    const docs: Documentation[] = [];

    const promises: { configItem: ConfigItem; promise: Promise<Response> }[] = [];

    CONFIG.forEach((value: ConfigItem[], key: string) => {
        value.forEach((configItem: ConfigItem) => {
            if (!configItem.subItem) {
                const promise = get(configItem.path);
                promises.push({ configItem, promise });
            }
        });
    });

    await Promise.all(promises).then(values => {
        values.forEach(entry => {
            const doc: Documentation = { path: '', rawText: '' };
            entry.promise
                .then(response => {
                    if (!response.ok) {
                        return Promise.reject(response);
                    } else {
                        return response.text().then(textValue => {
                            doc.path = entry.configItem.path;
                            doc.rawText = textValue;
                        });
                    }
                })
                .catch(e => Dialog.error('Failed to load page.', e));
            docs.push(doc);
        });
    });

    console.log('here is docs object');
    console.log(docs);

    (await docs).forEach(element => {
        console.log('element.name');
        console.log(element.name);
    });
}
```

When trying to print out to the browser console, I can see the entire documents object populated when printing out the whole thing, but right after when trying to loop over it the object is empty.

[image]

I know this is due to the async nature of the get() request that returns a Promise< Response >, but I'm lost as how to fix it. I'm new to TS and promises/async code so any pointers would be great!

Comment: `await Promise.all(promises).then(values => {` is awaiting a promise that **doesn't** depend on the loop inside it finishing before resolving.

Comment: This is a good time to use `map` instead of `forEach`

Comment: so does the promise resolve before even setting doc.path & doc.rawText? and why a map instead of forEach? @Quentin

Comment: Yes. Because a map will give you an array of promises you can pass to `Promise.all` rather than you reinventing map with `forEach`, `push`, and an array in a wider scope.

Comment: what would the code look like for map in this case? i get calling .map() on an existing array and setting the result equal to some new map variable, but not sure how to apply that to the loop over CONFIG when CONFIG is Map<string, ConfigItem[]>